# compile mod_wsgi without root privilege

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, mod-wsgi

I need to compile mod_wsgi without root privileges on CentOS. There is a precompiled version of mod_wsgi on the system but it is for python2.6. My django app requires python2.7 and hence I need to compile mod_wsgi with python2.7 I have downloaded and compiled python2.7 and created a virtualenv. Now I am using that to compile mod_wsgi: `./configure --with-python=/MYHOME/.MYENV/bin/python2.7`. The configure step works out fine, and so does `make`. However, when I do `make install`, I get an error:

```
cp: cannot create regular file `/usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_wsgi.so': Permission denied
apxs:Error: Command failed with rc=65536`
```

No surprise, since I am not root. What can I do now, is it possible to tell apache to load `mod_wsgi.so` from another location? I can probably ask a sys-admin to edit apache config files.

EDIT: I should have mentioned that my http.conf file contains a directive `Include /path/to/user-owned/directory/*.conf`. I am looking for an option that requires as little intervention from the sys-admin as possible.

Comment: If you can ask admin to edit apache config file, ask him to compile mod_wsgi.

Comment: if you dont have root privileges how are you going to copy it into Apache's directory and/or edit Apache config?

Comment: ok, good point yedpodtrzitko. I should have mentioned this in my question. The http.conf contains `Include /path/to/user-owned/directory/*.conf`.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to work this out with help from the sys-admin.

After configuring mod_wsgi with `./configure --with-python=/MYHOME/.MYENV/bin/python2.7` I edited the Makefile, inserting the following: `DESTDIR=/path/to/local/dir`.

Then `make` and `make install` run without error, as mod_wsgi.so is written to a permitted directory.

In the apache config file (the one I can edit without root privileges, thanks to `Include /path/to/user-owned/directory/*.conf`) , I set `LoadModule wsgi_module /path/to/local/dir/mod_wsgi.so`.

Hope this helps anyone with a similar setup.